# Select the Paper Source

Tags: wpf, printing

Can someone point me in the right direction here?  I've got a WPF application, and I'd like to be able to query a printer to see which paper trays are available.

In Windows Forms, I can use `PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources`

Does anybody know the WPF equivalent?

Comment: The [`PrintCapabilities.InputBinCapability`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printcapabilities.inputbincapability.aspx) property and the [`InputBin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.inputbin.aspx) enumeration are your friends.

Comment: And [PrintTickets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.aspx) to select the bin.  A little more exposition on the subject will prevent your answer from getting converted to a comment.